# UWP prevent multiple windows from being opened on the phone

Tags: c#, uwp

i´ve got a UWP App which runs on PC and phone.
I am using this [Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views) and it works fine.

But I now I want to hide the button on the phone to open the second window.

If I understood correctly, I shouldn't use the device class to determine that.
It´s better to use the ApiInformation class for this, for example to recognize the hardware buttons like this

```
Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons")
```

I can´t find the right string to ask if the device can handle multiple windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily` and compare it on desktop and mobile. According to availability across SDKs, `AnalyticsInfo` API is present since 10240 build so you have nothing to worry about.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.analyticsversioninfo